# Designing C# entities for Azure cosmos DB and EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, ef-core-3.1

I am fairly new to Azure cosmos db or NoSQL as a whole. As part of my system design, I have two entities `PrintGroup` and `PrintDocument` as below:

```
class PrintGroup
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PrintDocument> Documents { get; set; }
}

class PrintDocument
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For my cosmos container, I need to save individual PrintDocuments as well as embed it in the PrintGroup documents. I am using EFCore 3.1 with cosmos provider and my configuration is as below:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PrintGroup> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.OwnsMany<PrintDocument>(p => p.Documents);
    }
```

But when I do this, it only embeds the documents and does not save the print documents separately.
[image]
I need print documents because it serves as master data for various clients that can then configure them for their print contexts. If I remove the `builder.OwnsMany<Document>(p => p.Documents);` statement, it adds the individual print documents but does not embed them in the print context and I will then require to fetch the documents separately. This leaves me with an option to create separate entities for `PrintDocument` which is something I want to avoid doing.

I went through some entity design guides for EFcore with cosmos db, but the examples mentioned are very basic and does not cover a scenario where my entity model needs to generate hybrid data on the cosmos db.

Please suggest a way to implement this or if there is any inherent change that I can do in the way my data is modeled and the entity design as well.

Comment: Relevant? [*Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data).

Comment: @Richard I took this reference with my initial data model design in cosmos db. But it does not provide a sample for modelling hybrid model in EF Core entities.

Comment: Do you want the PrintDocument to be embedded as well as saved separately? Could you please provide the expected document format.

Comment: @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT what you mentioned is correct. I want to use the same entity to save separate document as well as embed it in the document as I have in the screen dump.

Comment: Duplicate data in the same document? That doesn't seem right. However if you still want to implement it, you are better off with a custom model class that combines both entities.

Comment: @Mustafa It will not automatically add the PrintDocument you've to add it manually. Hybrid Data modeling creates weak entity relations. In your case, PrintDocument will be a separate entity when you create the .OwnOne fluent improves your read with PrintGroup because all data is included in its document... you need to store PrintDocument separately as a standalone document.